# Which type of Riemann Sum is the most accurate?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

**When estimating the area under a curve, is it more accurate to average out the values of the upper and lower sums or use the midpoints of the intervals instead?**

I would assume it varies but I just wanted to know what the best way is to estimate the area under a curve when no instructions on how to do so have been given.

Comment: All the methods you have listed are only estimates. None of them are exact. The 'best' way of finding the area is integration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is about the error analysis of Numerical Methods of approximating a definite integral.

Both midpoint rule and  trapezoidal rule have a global error  which is $O(h^2)$ where $h=(b-a)/n$  is the step size.

That means if you double your $n$ the error divides by $4$.

Among the midpoint and the trapezoidal rules, the midpoint is the better choice because its error estimate is half of the trapezoidal rule.

The error estimate for trapezoidal rule is $$ -\frac {(b-a)h^2}{12}f''(\eta)$$While the error estimate for the midpoint rule is $$ \frac {(b-a)h^2}{24}f''(\eta)$$where $\eta \in [a,b]$ depends on the function.

Comment: Note that the two $\eta$'s are different in general.  While midpoint is "usually" better, there are cases where the trapezoidal rule turns out to be better.

Comment: The midpoint error can be larger than the trapezoidal error when the integrand exhibits a high degree of curvature in a small subinterval. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1771002/148510).

Comment: There are [other quadrature methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) that converge even faster.

Comment: Yes, Simpson Method, comes next. Gaussian quadrature is a jem and many Gaussian type quadratures exist.